# Happy 1 year anniversary!

Tags: discussion, thanks, congratulations, celebration

365 days ago we entered Private Beta and I am almost in tears thinking how far we have come since then!

Thank you to all the people who have participated, and congratulations to [those that got the yearling badge on the main site](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) and especially to [those that got it on the meta site](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling).